# Query a table in Back4app

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, back4app

I have a User table in Back4app. I would like to query the table. I am using the below set of statement. It does not work. Please advise. The count always comes to zero.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"%lu", objects.count);
    PFObject *obj = [objects firstObject];
    NSLog(@"%@", obj);
    NSString *str=[obj valueForKey:@"password"];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

PFQuerys for PFUsers should be instantiated via `[PFUser query]`

So, you should replace this line

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
```

with this line

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
```

Hope this helps :)